# How to disable Automatic Login for ssh key?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I had ticked the *'Automatically Unlock this key'* option when I was entering the password to unlock my ssh key, so now I'll be logged in automatically, although I did not mean to. How can I revert this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "Passwords and keys" system application. Go to the passwords database, somewhere there should be your stored password - just delete it.